# How to add code to a blog to view

Tags: php, ckeditor, blogs, tinymce-4

I am looking to create my own blog where I will do some textual posts along with some tutorial blogs.

Does TinyMCE or CKeditor allow me to add code so that it will be shown both like the code version below here and output it so the user can see the end result ie for when showing divs.

```
<?php echo "hello";?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [TinyMCe demo plugin](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/basic.php) :

http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/basic.php

Go to Formats / Formats / Blocks / Pre

It should works to show code in your article. But the Highlight is very basic with <pre>. You should search for a plugin. There were plugins for tinyMce 3 like this [tinymce-pre-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/tinymce-pre-plugin/)

For tinyMce V4, try this one :

plugin link:
https://github.com/ahmedsaoud31/snippet

demo :
http://goo2pro.com/myFiles/examples/snippet/

Answer (score 0):

if you are using wordpress then i would like to suggest plugins like,Syntax Highlighter for WordPress, WP Code Highlight